# IsEnabled and IsHitTestVisible overrides Cursor set to wait

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm writing a WPF app, sometimes I have to indicate that the app is busy, I want to set the cursor to `Wait` (the spinny thing), but I also want to universally disable interaction with the app.

this works for setting the cursor to `Wait`:

```
<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="UserControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>
```

But when I try to disable the whole app by changing IsHitTestVisible:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait"/>
    <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="True"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

The cursor just becomes an arrow, same if I use `IsEnabled` in place of `IsHitTestVisible`

As far as I understand, if the control is not "hit visible" the it does not get to set the cursor, but I can't think of a nice way to get around this.

Comment: on which control have you put this DataTrggers? Was binding of IsBusy working fine?

Comment: @KyloRen it is a `UserControl`... it's a custom control within my application. The binding is working fine.

Comment: how did you ensure that binding is working fine? did you tried changing background color etc?  Also Cursor Revert means first it changed to wait then again to arrow?

Comment: @KyloRen I know the binding works because `IsHitTestVisible` is set to false (the app does not respond to clicks), and because when the `IsHitTestVisible`is removed the mouse cursor does change and because I get no binding errors and because I snooped it. I can change the background as well but I hardly see the point... And, no, I didn't mean that it changes and then changes back I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `true` does not allow your window to be aware if the mouse is over itself of not. Therefore the window does not know when the cursor indicator should be changed.

Then I suggest to you a *workaround*: just put a `Border` *over* your window content and let make this border decide when your user interface is busy or not.

This is what I mean: in your window use this XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Application.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Panel.ZIndex="100">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait" />
                            <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Wait" />
                            <Setter Property="ForceCursor" Value="True" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <!-- Your Controls, i.e. your window's content -->
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see the `Border` has an higher `ZIndex` than the rest of your window's content. When the binded property `IsBusy` is `true`, then the `Border` is visible and it does not allow the user to interact with the window's controls.

If `IsBusy` is `false`, the `Border` is collapsed and everything works as usual.

Comment: Based on your solution, I simply put a border around the component. The border sets the "Cursor" and the component sets "IsEnabled".